# preview merges pdf and result in huge file size?

Tags: pdf, preview

I used preview to merge 5 pdf files, of total size of 800k. All pdf have no graphs. However the resulting file size is 10MB...

I then tried Acrobat, under similar simple method I got a combined pdf of 750kb.

So why is preview so inefficient? Or Have I just misconfigured sth.?

Answer (score 5):

I can't really answer as to why it's so inefficient, but i've had the same problem, and i got around it by using free Quartz filters from Jerome Colas.

[This post on the Apple discussion boards has the details](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1292868?start=0&tstart=0), but the link is broken, an extra * on the end breaks it, it should be https://public.me.com/jcolas.

Download, unzip, and add the "Filters" folder to your Library folder.

To use, open a PDF in Preview, click File > Save As, then select Quartz Filter, and the level of compression.
[image: Preview Save As dialog box]

I believe that Jerome is exposing something that [already exists in OSX](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8545.html), but certainly, it's a good solution that works well for me, allowing me to get a good balance between quality and filesize.